# Get IIS apps using powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

Please advice how to get the list of my IIS applications(it's names) using PowerShell script.

[image]

If I run Get-IISSite

the result is [image]

But I need all applications that is inside Default Web Site section.

Like to go through some foreach and retrieve all apps names that exists inside Default Web Site.

Comment: `Get-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool\` ?

Comment: Seems like it also shows the same info about Default Web Site...

Comment: The WebAdministration module might be useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/?view=windowsserver2022-ps - import using: `Import-Module WebAdministration -Verbose`

Comment: https://octopus.com/blog/iis-powershell Tons of examples are there. Note that you should use `IISAdministration` cmdlets instead of the legacy `WebAdministration` ones.

Comment: Hi, has your problem been solved?

Comment: Hi, yep with the answer below. Thanks!

Comment: If the answer below work for you, you can mark this answer as accepted, thank you!

Comment: Sure! I did it! Thank u SIr!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following PowerShell script:

```
(get-webapplication -Site "Default Web Site" | select-object @{n='Site'; e= {$_.GetParentElement().Attributes['name'].value + $_.path }},@{n='Location'; e= {$_.PhysicalPath}})
```

Below is the result of my test:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

If you only want to get all applications name of the Default Web Site, you can write a powershell script like this:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' | Where-Object {$_.NodeType -eq 'application'}).Name
```

[image: image3]